# How can I upload to a Google cloud storage server in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am at a loss on how to have unity send local files using the Google Storage API. I'm not incredibly fluent with C# in unity context so I'm not sure what is necessary to make it happen.